# Non-linear classification vs regression with FFANN

Tags: matlab, neural-network, classification, regression

I am trying to differentiate between two classes of data for forecasting. Basically the dependent variables are features of a signal that I want to forecast. I want to predict whether the signal will have a positive or negative slope in the near future (1 time step ahead). I have tried with different time series analysis, such as Fourier analysis, fitting using neural networks, auto-regressive models, and classification with neural nets (using patternet in Matlab).

The function is continuous, so the most logical assumption is to use some regression analysis tool to determine what's going to happen. However, since I only care whether the slope is going to positive or negative, I changed the signal to a binary signal (1 if the slope is positive, -1 if the slope is 0 or negative).

This is by the far the best results I have gotten! However, for some unknown reason a neural net designed for classification did not work (the confusion matrix stated that there was a precision of around 50%). So I decided to try with a regular feedforward neural net...

Since the neural network outputs continuous data, I didn't know what to do... But then I remembered about Logistic regression, and since its transfer function is a log function (bounded by 0 and 1), it can be interpreted as a probability. So I basically did the same, defined a threshold (e.g above 0 is 1, below 0 is -1), and voila! The precision sky-rocked! I am getting a precision of around 70-80%.

Since I am using a sigmoid transfer function, the neural network wll have a continuous output just as logistic regression (but on this case between -1 and 1), so I am assuming my approach is technically still regression and not classification.  My question is... **Which is better?** For my specific problem where fitting did not give really good results but I had to convert this to a binary problem... Which **should** give better results? Classification or regression?

Should I try a different configuration of a neural net (with a different transfer function), should I try with support vector machine or any other classification algorithm? Or should I stick with regression but defining a threshold myself just as I would do with logistic regression?